# Search bar jumps down one row every time cancel button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented a UISearchBar to search through a catalogue of items from an external API. The Search functionality works as expected, however the problem is that every time I press the cancel button, which is on the right side of the search bar text field, the whole search bar moves down by one row and it looks like it pushes the entire table view down as well.

So if I type a letter into the search bar text field, then press cancel, the search bar text field moves down by 44px, which is the row height, and the table view itself also gets pushed down by the same amount. If i continuously press type something, then press cancel, the search bar will move further and further down the view. Any advice would be great! Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ItemLogger


private extension Selector {
    static let dismiss = #selector(SearchVC.dismissView)
}


extension SearchVC: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
    }
}
extension SearchVC: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}

class SearchVC: UITableViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var searchedItems = [ItemLog]()
    var searchedImages = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back_Button"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: .dismiss)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        configureSearchController()
    }


    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    func configureSearchController() {

        guard !searchController.active else {
            return
        }

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Type to Search"

        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        let view: UIView = self.searchController.searchBar.subviews[0] as UIView
        for subView: UIView in view.subviews {
            if let textView = subView as? UITextField {
                textView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
                textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.05)
            }
        }
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.33)]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }



    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return searchedItems.count
        }

        return 0

    }

    override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("items", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(111) as! UILabel
        let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(222) as! UILabel
        let art = cell.viewWithTag(333) as! UIImageView

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" && searchController.searchBar.text != NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet(){

            label.text = searchedItems[indexPath.row].title
            nameLabel.text = searchedItems[indexPath.row].name
            art.image = searchedImages[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print(searchedItems[indexPath.row])
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }


    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {


        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" && searchController.searchBar.text != NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet() {
            let queries: [SearchQueryOptions] = [
                .QueryString(searchController.searchBar.text!)]
            ItemLog.search(queries, completion: { (result) in
                if let itms = result.response.result where itms.count > 0 {
                    self.searchedItems.removeAll()
                    self.searchedImages.removeAll()
                    for i in 0...itms.count - 1 {

                        self.searchedItems.append(itms[i])
                        self.searchedImages.append(itms[i].img)

                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }


    func dismissView(){
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Update your question with your storyboard  and your runtime result .

Comment: @MikeG check my answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code tested in Swift 3.

Note: When, I, try your code. I was facing the same issue. Somehow, I managed to get around...

```
class SearchVC: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultUpdating {

var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     configureSearchController()
 }


override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {

    return true
}


func configureSearchController() {

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        controller.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        //controller.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "xxxx")!)
        // controller.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "xxxx"), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Top, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        //  controller.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "xxxx")
        // controller.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "search-icon.png"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)

        return controller
    })()


    for subView in self.resultSearchController.searchBar.subviews
    {
        for subsubView in subView.subviews
        {
            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField
            {
                textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Search Text", comment: ""), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

                textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true


                textField.textColor = UIColor.red
                textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
                textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

                textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.215

            }
         }  
      }
   }
}
```

**Updated:**

```
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {}
```

Output from above code..hope, my answer will fix your problem....
[image]

Comment: Awesome! After testing a bit I notice that it had something to with the searchBar `scope`. Still not sure exactly what it was but a combination of your answer and some tinkering did the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I've made an open source project [SearchTableView](https://github.com/rishi420/SearchTableView)

```
self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar

searchTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
definesPresentationContext = true
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `configureSearchController()` in `viewDidLoad`.
And don't forget to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated:)` in your `viewWillAppear`.