# UISearchBar searchBarCancelButtonClicked not being called using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar

For some reason when I click the circle x cancel button in a UISearchBar the **searchBarCancelButtonClicked** event is not firing, it worked in a swift 2 project but not in this swift 3 one.

I am now extending my view controller instead of the inline class way but I believe that is working as the **searchBarSearchButtonClicked** event does work. Here is what I have so far:

```
extension MyViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      print("here?")
      searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
      handleCancelSearch()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        if let searchText = searchBar.text {
            performSearchUsing(term:searchText)
        }

    }
}
```

The print is not logged and the function not called. Am I missing something silly?

Comment: Check my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982355/search-bar-jumps-down-one-row-every-time-cancel-button-is-tapped/40090565#40090565  it will solve your problem..

Comment: try searchBar.isActive = false .Inside your searchBarCancelButtonClicked....this should fix your problem....

Comment: Make sure you set your view controller as the delegate, and add 'public' in front of the delegate method.

Comment: Where did you embed searchBar? I had the same problems when I tried to put it in navigationBar titleView or in collectionView header. When I created standalone empty view, that acts as placeholder, delegation methods started to be called.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are missing something silly as I did, the "circle x" is not actually the cancel button, and I thought that too, the cancel button comes disabled by default, you can activate it via storyboard on the attributes of the searchBar or you can do it programmatically with:

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
```

After that, the method should work.

Answer (score 1):

If any one still looking for the option how act on "X" button. use below method which is available in

```
UISearchBarDelegate 

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    if searchText.count == 0
    {   // Hide content

    }
}
```

Note : it is not cannel button its clear text button which is visible after typing something in searchBar