# UISearchController view keeps getting pushed down when push-popping controllers from searchResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem regarding the UISearchController component. I have set up a searchcontroller like this:

```
let searchResultsController = TSSearchResultsController(nibName: "TSSearchResultsController", bundle: nil)
searchResultsController.delegate = self
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
searchController.delegate = self

// SearchController
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

// SearchBar
searchController.searchBar.delegate = searchResultsController
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = IDAssetManager.getColorWhite()
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

...

When I click the search result I push a view onto the navigationstack which is defined in the same place I initialise the searchController. When I come back, the searchController view has been pushed down a few a bit. This is continuously happening every time I push and pop from navigationController. I have tried self.extendedEdgesForLayout = [] but does not help.

Comment: Use appropriate formatting for your code

Comment: this post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982355/search-bar-jumps-down-one-row-every-time-cancel-button-is-tapped/40090565#40090565